# Google Adding Strange Directory Name To Site Links

Tags: asp.net, url, seo

I have just been asked to find out why a clients website be listed in Google in an interesting way. Some of the links have an extra directory with a (seemingly) random name.

The url.
http://www.servicedofficecompany.co.uk/resources/

Is listed by google as.
http://www.servicedofficecompany.co.uk/(A(khbmZF83yQEkAAAAZGQ1OThhMmQtNzA4Zi00NmVmLWI4ZDUtMTA4ZmRmYjgzZWVmjkz4KVF6yNl_4UvHnUcR51UunJw1)S(sbkd2nyztm23yk555lbbtgzl))/resources/

This is not happening on all pages but you can see examples by using the below Google query. Anyone got any idea's?

site:servicedofficecompany.co.uk

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your site is detecting that googlebot does not support cookies, and is therefore redirecting it to a URL that contains the session ID.

For info on ASP.NET cookieless session support, see e.g. [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx)

Comment: You're right.  I edited my question to include that possibility right after you, apparently.  Removing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonas, I remeber where I'd seen URLS like that before. More .NET cleverness driving me mad.